# How to login using facebook In my webview app without typing my username and password

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, webview

I have a wordpress website where my users can login using their facebook accounts and post on my website.

I have created a webview android app and it is working fine but to login you have to enter your username and password 
And I am afraid that it would rais some security concerns from the users
[image]

Is there a way where my app can be login using facebook app and without asking for the pasword

Comment: Using the Facebook API is the best and safest way.

Comment: Is it possible to use it with a webview app? I need to login an external website using the app

Comment: No its not possible with a `WebView`. But if your website is safe then it would be safe to do it in the way that you are currently doing it.

Comment: But, I agree with you users will not be comfortable. I would recommend creating a native application instead of using webviews.